sin approximation with a 2 layer neural network
I have written this code:
import numpy as np
    
# Define the number of samples
num_points = 1000

# Generate data
x_values = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, num_points)
y_values = np.sin(x_values)

# Randomly select 100 samples for the training set
train_indices = np.random.choice(num_points, size=100, replace=False)
x_train = x_values[train_indices]
y_train = y_values[train_indices]

# Use the remaining samples for the test set
test_indices = np.array([i for i in range(num_points) if i not in train_indices])
x_test = x_values[test_indices]
y_test = y_values[test_indices]

# Initialize the model parameters
def initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y):
    W1 = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) 
    b1 = np.random.randn(n_h, 1)
    W2 = np.random.randn(n_h, n_h)
    b2 = np.random.randn(n_h, 1)
    W3 = np.random.randn(n_y, n_h)
    b3 = np.random.randn(n_y, 1)
    parameters = {"W1": W1, "b1": b1, "W2": W2, "b2": b2, "W3": W3, "b3": b3}
    return parameters

# Define the activation function (ReLU)
def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

# Define the activation function (linear)
def linear(x):
    return x

# Define the activation function (sigmoid)
def sigmoid(x):
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return s

# Define the activation function (Tanh)
def Tanh(x):
  p = (np.exp(x) - np.exp(-x)) / (np.exp(x) + np.exp(-x))
  return p

# Forward propagation
def forward_propagation(parameters, X):
    # retrieve the parameters from the input
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    b1 = parameters["b1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    b2 = parameters["b2"]
    W3 = parameters["W3"]
    b3 = parameters["b3"]

    # compute the forward propagation
    z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
    a1 = ?(z1)
    z2 = np.dot(W2, a1) + b2
    a2 = ?(z2)
    z3 = np.dot(W3, a2) + b3
    a3 = ?(z3) 

    temp_cache = {"z1": z1, "a1": a1, "z2": z2, "a2": a2, "z3": z3, "a3": a3}
    return a3, temp_cache

# Mean squared error loss function
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean((y_true - y_pred) ** 2)

# Back propagation
def backward_propagation(parameters, temp_cache, x_train, y_train):
    # retrieve the parameters from the input
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    W3 = parameters["W3"]
    a1 = temp_cache["a1"]
    a2 = temp_cache["a2"]
    a3 = linear(z3)

    # compute the backward_propagation
    dz3 = a3 - y_train
    dW3 = np.dot(dz3, a2.T) / num_points
    db3 = np.sum(dz3, axis=1, keepdims=True) / num_points

    dz2 = np.dot(W3.T, dz3) * Tanh(a2, derivative=True)
    dW2 = np.dot(dz2, a1.T) / num_points
    db2 = np.sum(dz2, axis=1, keepdims=True) / num_points

    dz1 = np.dot(W2.T, dz2) * sigmoid(a1, derivative=True)
    dW1 = np.dot((x_train.reshape(-1,1)).T, dz1) / num_points
    db1 = np.sum(dz1, axis=1, keepdims=True) / num_points

    gradients = {"dW1": dW1, "db1": db1, "dW2": dW2, "db2": db2, "dW3": dW3, "db3": db3}
    return gradients

# update the parameters
def update_parameters(parameters, gradients, learning_rate):
    # retrieve the parameters from the input
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    b1 = parameters["b1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    b2 = parameters["b2"]
    W3 = parameters["W3"]
    b3 = parameters["b3"]
    
    # retrieve the gradient from the input
    dW1 = gradients["dW1"]
    db1 = gradients["db1"]
    dW2 = gradients["dW2"]
    db2 = gradients["db2"]
    dW3 = gradients["dW3"]
    db3 = gradients["db3"]
    
    # update the parameters after comparing
    W1 = W1 - learning_rate * dW1
    b1 = b1 - learning_rate * db1
    W2 = W2 - learning_rate * dW2
    b2 = b2 - learning_rate * db2
    W3 = W3 - learning_rate * dW3
    b3 = b3 - learning_rate * db3

    parameters = {"W1": W1, "b1": b1, "W2": W2, "b2": b2, "W3": W3, "b3": b3}
    return parameters

learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 100
n_h = 8

def nn_1layer_1batch(x_train, y_train, n_h, learning_rate, num_epochs, print_cost=False):
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    #set up
    n_x = x_train.shape[0]
    n_y = y_train.shape[0]

    # initialize parameters
    parameters = initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y)

    # Forward propagation
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,1)
    y_pred, temp_cache = forward_propagation(parameters, x_train)

    # Backward propagation (gradient computation)
    gradients = backward_propagation(parameters, temp_cache, x_train, y_train)

    # Update the parameters
    parameters = update_parameters(parameters, gradients, learning_rate)

    # Compute the training loss
    train_loss = mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_train)
    if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}')

# Evaluate the model on the test set
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1,1)
n_x = x_test.shape[0]``
n_y = y_test.shape[0]
parameters = initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y)
y_test_pred, q = forward_propagation(parameters, x_test)
test_loss = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)
print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}')

# Plot the results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, label='True Values')
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test_pred, label='Predicted Values')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Sinusoidal Function Approximation')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


I am trying to approximate the sin function. but I don't know which and in what order my activation functions should be. right now my predicted y values look like they have been randomly valued.
I tried different orders of activation functions but none of these trials provided a desirable result.

Your code is incomplete, the Tanh function is missing its derivative implemetation,... With relu and tanh you essentially produce piecewise linear functions (mollified with tanh) with the layer sizes producing the number of sampling points. For the sine you need 6-20 points per period to get something visually appropriate. The 2 layers a 10 points might be sufficient. Initial random parameters require initial bold learning steps, your step size might be too small.
